# Text doesn't show up on part of the page HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website that has a horizontal parallax scrolling. However, for some strange reason I can't get the text on the first slide(I'm trying to get the words Home to show up on the page that it scrolls to after you click the Home button at the top) to show up. For all the other pages, the words all appear except not on the first one. I've tried this on JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/LZfsV/) and it shows up, but just not on the page itself. I've tried debugging with Firebug, and Firebug tells me that the area where the text is supposed to show up is there, just I can't see it.  Any ideas? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="transition-slide-container">
<!--begin transition-slide-container-->
<div id="transition-slide">
    <div class="slide" id="home">
        <div id="inner-container">
             <h1>home</h1> 

        </div>
        <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="portfolio">
        <div id="inner-container">
             <h1>portfolio</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="about">
        <div id="inner-container">
            <h1>about</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="contact">
        <div id="inner-container">
             <h1>Contact</h1> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#transition-slide-container {
    background: #bee1ff;
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
div#transition-slide {
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0;
}
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 24.999999%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: 1px #000 solid;
}
div#inner-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/#home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a z-index of -1 defined for your container, remove it and you should be fine

```
div#transition-slide-container {
    /* z-index: -1; remove this */
}
```

Comment: Z-index defines the order in which element appear layered on screen, a negative value means the element will appear below `body` and since body has a solid background-color it will cover the element. As to why it only affects the first tab, my guess is because the other elements first render outside the viewport and the browser is not applying the z-index calculations on them?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
z-index: -1;
```

from the following

```
div#transition-slide-container {
    background: #bee1ff;
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
```